# "class" Keyword on Return Type - C++

Tags: c++

I came across a piece of code that looked like this:

```c++
class SomeClass* GetSomeClass()
{
  return _instanceOfSomeClass;
}
```

What does the "class" keyword do on the return type? I can't find anywhere that explains what it's function is. Does it just specify that it's talking about SomeClass as a class in case there is some sort of ambiguousness or something? I am confused.

Comment: This is _very_ nearly http://stackoverflow.com/q/29580288/560648

Answer (score 24, accepted):

`class SomeClass` is a longhand way of referring to the class type `SomeClass` (technically, it's the *elaborated type specifier*). Usually, adding `class` is redundant, and the two are equivalent. But it's sometimes necessary to resolve the ambiguity, if there's a variable or function with the same name.

Answer (score 14):

It is used to disambiguate.

Say for example if you have a variable of the same name in the same (or outer) scope, something like this:

```
int SomeClass; //SomeClass is declared to be variable here

class SomeClass* GetSomeClass()
{
  return _instanceOfSomeClass;
}
```

Without the `class` keyword, the function declaration wouldn't make sense to the compiler. The `class` keyword tells the compiler to ignore the variable declaration, and look for a class declaration.

Answer (score 9):

It's a forward declaration. It allows you to just say "there is a class SomeClass somewhere in my program, it is just not visible to this file in order to prevent redeclerations".

Whenever you implement this function, though, the file must have actual interface of class SomeClass.

Comment: While true technically I believe you missed a few nuances of the question.